# Using generator function to find if a rule has been broken

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am trying to transform a function that checks the state of a game by checking that all rules that apply are being obeyed. If a rule is broken, the entire check fails meaning the game is in an invalid state.

```
def check():
    if not check_rule1():
        return False

    if not check_rule2():
        return False

    # ....

    if not check_ruleN():
        return False
```

As you can see the main problem in this function is the multiple return points, that's why I was trying to make this function using a generator but I must be thick today because I am not getting it right. This is what I have tried:

```
import random

violation_found = False

def check_rule1():
    violation = not random.randint(0, 1)
    print 'Checking Rule #1 ->', violation
    violation_found = violation

def check_rule2():
    violation = not random.randint(0, 1)
    print 'Checking Rule #2 ->', violation
    violation_found = violation

def check_rule3():
    violation = not random.randint(0, 1)
    print 'Checking Rule #3 ->', violation
    violation_found = violation

def check_all_rules():
    check_rule1(*rule1_args, **rule1_kwargs)
    yield
    check_rule2(*rule2_args, **rule2_kwargs)
    yield
    check_rule3(*rule3_args, **rule3_kwargs)
    yield

def check():
    for rule in check_all_rules():
        if violation_found:
            return False
    return True

check()
```

And unexpectedly, it is not breaking the iteration once a violation is found, but it goes through all the `yield` statements:

```
Checking Rule #1 -> False
Checking Rule #2 -> True
Checking Rule #3 -> False
```

It should have stopped at rule #2. What am I missing?

Comment: `violation_found` in `check` is the global variable (which is always False)

Comment: ok I see it now, thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write it as the following:

```
passes_checks = all(rule() for rule in (check_rule1, check_rule2, check_rule3))
```

So you loop over and call each rule in turn and you only get a `True` result if all rule checks return `True` (or a true like value), otherwise, you get a `False` and checking will stop there and then without running further checks.

Okay, if the arguments are different, then raise a custom exception when the rule fails, and return true when no exceptions are raised, eg:

```
class RuleError(Exception):
    pass

def check_rule1(*args, **kwargs):
    # Fail
    raise RuleError('rule 1 failed')

def check_rule2(name, fruit='apple', *args, **kwargs):
    if name != 'bob':
        raise RuleError('rule 2 - name must be bob')

def check(to_check, *args, **kwargs):
    for f in to_check:
        try:
            f(*args, **kwargs)
        except RuleError as e:
            # do something meaningful or re-raise... etc...
            print(e)
            return False
        else:
            return True

passes_checks = check([check_rule1, check_rule2], 'something', name='bob')
```

Comment: I need to keep the `check_ruleN` functions in **one** function because they receive different arguments (these arguments would be fetched/calculated in that one function)

Comment: @dabadaba okay... your example code doesn't even imply that's the case :)

Comment: also I guess you should mention each `check_ruleN` should return a boolean instead, as per my current example your solution wouldn't work

Comment: well, actually, your solution is not using generators at all, is it?

Comment: @dabadaba `rule() for rule in (check_rule1, check_rule2, check_rule3)` is a generator...

Comment: well yeah true that but my original question mentions generator function, not generator expression

Comment: your edit solution looks pretty smooth, but you're passing the same `args` and `kwargs` to all functions right? each function have their specific ones, as I noted in my original post edit

Comment: @dabadaba right... where do the args and kwargs come from for each of those though? (are they hanging around as globals somewhere or hard-wired to each check for instance?)

Comment: as I mentioned, they would be fetched/calculated in the one function that calls each rule check function

Comment: @dabadaba how much do the check functions signatures vary?

Comment: significantly enough

Comment: @dabadaba could you not force them to always accept `**kwargs` and name the arguments you require as named arguments... should cover most cases

Comment: hmmm that's actually certainly worth considering, I can even take advantage of it since in some scenarios some of these functions actually have share some arguments

Comment: @dabadaba okay - added a check_rule2 as a kind of example in case it's needed

Comment: oh it's pretty elegant and all but I see a problem now: most of these args passed to each function should be retrieved right before the function is called, since they are costly to get, that's why I was very specific in use just one function to call those rule checking function in sucession

Comment: So each check has to get its own context? eg: it's not a set of different checks against the same thing - it's more a series of checks that all needed to pass, but not against the same thing

Comment: the context is partially shared, but some/many data each check deals with is specific to each check, and costly to process

Comment: yeah it is not against the same thing but some of these checks do have some of the same args

Comment: I just answered you in the chat, sorry didn't see it before. I wish SO notified new chat messages.